# Octal escape sequence out of range

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am currently trying to by pass a proxy but the compiler is giving me a warning message
"Octal escape sequence out of range"

```
  NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"asdfg\123456"
                                                             password:@"Zxcvb123!" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
```

How i can remove this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If '\' is just a part of your user credentials you need to escape it:

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"asdfg\\123456"
                                                             password:@"Zxcvb123!" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your \ (backslash) in the user name. The \ is an escape character and when used as \121 it interprets 121 as an octal number. If you want n actual \ in the username you should write it as

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"asdfg\\123456"
                                               password:@"Zxcvb123!"
                                               persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession] ;
```